# Doxygen section indentation issues

Tags: indentation, doxygen

[image]

Is this normal? What am I missing here? thanks.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Please don't supply code in the form of images but as text in the question so, when necessary, we can test it! The `TAB_SIZE` has nothing to do with the resulting indentation of sections etc. but is only about the input code so doxygen knows which tab size is intended and can be translated to spaces especially when in code. So yes the result is as expected.

Comment: oh sorry about that, so what should I do to add tab indentations to my documentation? thanks.

Comment: Direct regarding the resulting HTML code there is not a lot you can do as the resulting `<h..>`, `<p>` etc. are not nested or have a `class` attribute attached to them. You can generate XML code `GENERATE_XML=YES` and process this.

Comment: oh I wasn't aware you could add html code! wraping the section in a <pre> will do it!

Comment: Wrapping it in `<pre>` will do it? I see that the headers are not indented and that the text is set in a fixed format, I don't think that is what you want as you will also loose e.g down features.